# JPA and Database Level User Authorization

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I am supposed to build a `Java EE` Webapp on a legacy `MsSql Database`.

It is corporate security policy to use and respect database level user authentication and table level user roles and authorization per user.

This means, I need to create a database connection per user with the credentials of the user.

Is there any way to achieve this in standard `JPA` or do I have to implement my own connection pool? And if I did, what are the consequences? Would I be able to use container managed transactions?

I could not find any documentation or best practices on this scenario for `JPA`, but there is a number of `DBA` handbooks that recommend this kind of database level user auditing strategy.

So whats the best practice to work with a `JavaEE` stack on this kind of database?

Comment: Sounds like EclipseLink's VPD support for the Oracle database might be worth looking into: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/multitenancy004.htm#CHDJEBAC  This might be done for your database platform as well with some changes to the platform class

Comment: I solved this by creating an instance of EntityManager per session with the credentials of the user.